# Is there a way to add album art to mka files with encoded chapters?

Tags: music, matroska, album-art

I typically use MP3Tag to add album art to any music file. However, I have noticed that .mka files with chapters cannot have an album art attached to them. MP3Tag registers each individual chapter in that file as separate music files.

Is there any way I could collectively tag an album art on to the .mka file as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use mkvmerge CLI/GUI: https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html

```
mkvmerge.exe --output E:\output.mka --audio-tracks 1 --no-video --no-subtitles 
--no-attachments --language 1:und --track-name "1:Johnny Cash - Ring of Fire" 
--compression 1:none "E:\file1.mka" --attachment-name cover.png               
--attachment-mime-type image/png --attach-file E:\cover.png                   
--title "Johnny Cash - Ring of Fire" --probe-range-percentage 0.50
```

note that image name must be always named "cover"